# NSDictionary from plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

Here is my problem.

I can't convert my plist data (serialized in JSON) into NSDictionary.

To save data in my application I'm writing in a plist file this way.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[MyUser sharedUser] userID]] forKey:@"userID"];
    [dict setObject:[[MyUser sharedUser] firstname] forKey:@"firstname"];
    [dict setObject:[[MyUser sharedUser] lastname] forKey:@"lastname"];
    [dict setObject:[[MyUser sharedUser] mail] forKey:@"mail"];
    [dict setObject:[[MyUser sharedUser] pwd] forKey:@"pwd"];
    [dict setObject:[[MyUser sharedUser] token] forKey:@"token"];
    [dict setObject:[[MyUser sharedUser] picture] forKey:@"picture"];

    NSData *putData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:putData, nil];
    [array writeToFile:[self getSaveFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

When I want to load data from plist to get my NSDictionary.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *myPath = [self getSaveFilePath];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
    if (fileExists)
    {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
        NSLog(@"%@", data);
        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", s);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

`s` is equal to : (same as my file content when I open it in Fraise)

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <data>
    eyJsYXN0bmFtZSI6IkRvbm5pbmdlciIsImR0ZWxscyI6IlRPT00iLCJpc0RDYXJkUHJv
    RGVmYXVsdCI6ImluZGl2aWR1YWwiLCJzZW5kaW5nSW52aXQiOiJzbXMiLCJpc0F1dG9E
    bCI6IjAiLCJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiJUaG9tYXMiLCJjb250YWN0TGlzdCI6eyJtZXNzYWdl
    IjoiUmVjb3JkKHMpIEZvdW5kIiwic3VjY2VzcyI6dHJ1ZSwiZGF0YSI6eyJ0b3RhbENv
    dW50IjozLC [....]
</data>
</array>
</plist>
```

I don't know what to do with my string to convert it into NSDictionary.
How can I get NSDictionary from the plist?

Comment: I didn't say that, or I didn't mean that. Data stocked in plist are in JSON. Anyway SPA find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you're putting the NSData into an NSArray and using that to writeToFile, then you need to get it back as an NSArray first, then get the NSData object from that array

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:myPath];

 NSData *data = array[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the `NSArray` and JSON?

```
[dict writeToFile:[self getSaveFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

and

```
NSDictionary *restoredDictionary = [NSDictionary  dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self getSaveFilePath]];
```